# unable to launch kitchen sink app in titanium studio

Tags: git, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Im attempting to take a look at the kitchen sink app example through titanium studio and everytime I attempt to open and run the project it tells me git.exe has stopped working and shuts down, theres a few methods for launching the app however every way I have tried i get the same error any Ideas? I am running windows vista and using the android sdk if this helps

Comment: Did you use the PortableGit shipped with Titanium Studio or a separate git installation on Windows?

Comment: In addition to answering Michael, can you find out and provide the versions for a couple more things for us: what version of Titanium Studio you are running (ex. 1.0.4.201108051610)? And, somewhat less likely to influence your problem, but... What version of Titanium Mobile SDK are you using? And what version of the Kitchen Sink (where did you download it from)?